# Wordpress Vue Js Shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, rest-api

Currently i am developing a wordpress website with Vue.js and the wordpress REST API, and can't find a solution to use wordpress shortcodes
ex: `Contact Form 7`

I have been trying this example , but it doesn't seem to work with me
[Vue.js + AJAX Shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272550/vue-js-ajax-shortcode?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Anyone ever had a similar problem?

EDIT:

**For Example**

**In regular wordpress**

I can use the contact forms plug in this way

```
 <section class="container section__form display--grid">
    <div class="form__content display--flex width--full justify--center">
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="75" title="Formulário de contacto 1"]' ); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Since vue is on the client side and not directy connected to wordpress i can't use this way

I Thought that might be a way i could use the short code like a vue component or use php inside a vue component.

Comment: how do you want to use shortcode ? edit your question to show the code you tried.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you explain it in your question so that no prior knowledge of Vue.js and Contact Form 7 is necessary?

Comment: I am sorry working on it !

Comment: the edit is done

Comment: hmmm, are you using the ancient Admin AJAX like the question you linked to? Or are you using the modern REST API interface?

Comment: I'm working with the REST API

Comment: It must be a problem with my build.js because i can't understand where does it come from! and because of that my wp_localize_scripts isn't used in the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i got it :

In the `functions.php` i added the line :

```
 wp_localize_script('vue_wordpress.js','sharedData',array(
    'contactForm' => do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5" title="Formulário de contacto 1"]')
  )
```

to the already existing function i had:

```
 function vue_wordpress_scripts()
{
    // Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    // wp_enqueue_style('vue_wordpress.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/vue-wordpress.css');
    // wp_enqueue_style('global',get_template_directory() . '/styles/menu.css' ); //copiar este código para adicionar mais styles.  
    // Scripts
    // Enable For Production - Disable for Development
    // wp_enqueue_script('vue_wordpress.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/vue-wordpress.js', array(), null, true);
    // Enable For Development - Remove for Production
     wp_enqueue_script( 'vue_wordpress.js', 'http://localhost:8080/vue-wordpress.js', array(), false, true );

}
```

and i called the shortcode in the component.
The mistake was on my part.